# Unable to click enter after entering the search string in the website search box using selenium web driver

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors, selenium-firefoxdriver

I am trying to open the browser and enter the search item in the search input box and perform enter.

I am able to open the browser and able to enter the search keyword in the search box but i am unable to perform the enter. Also when i enter the keyword , i get few list of suggestion that i could not select the first item. I am not sure what is going wrong with the code.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as wait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

browser = webdriver.Firefox()

browser.get("https://www.tickertape.in/stocks/")
browser.maximize_window()
inputElement=browser.find_element_by_id('search-stock-input')
inputElement.click()
inputElement.send_keys('Reliance industries')
inputElement.click()
```

I tried below two options to click/enter the list but i am not able to select/enter it.

```
inputElement = wait(browser, 5).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.Select-option#"react-autowhatever-1-section-0-item-1')))
inputElement.click()


actions = ActionChains(browser)
actions.move_to_element(inputElement).click().send_keys('Reliance industries')
actions.perform()
```

This is the HTML.

```
//*[@id="search-stock-input"]

<input type="search" value="Reliance Industries" autocomplete="off" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-controls="react-autowhatever-1" class="jsx-4060663325 stock-input-box full-width" placeholder="Search stocks, indices, ETFs, Mutual Funds or brands" maxlength="80" id="search-stock-input" aria-label="search text">

<div id="react-autowhatever-1" role="listbox" class="jsx-513088474 jsx-507199909 jsx-145021258 react-autosuggest__suggestions-container"><ul class="jsx-513088474 jsx-507199909 jsx-145021258 d-flex tags-list"></ul><div class="jsx-513088474 jsx-507199909 jsx-145021258 assets-suggestion-container "></div></div>
```

This is website screenshot
[image: Screenshot]

Thanks in advance

Comment: I will do as as I did not know that I need to accept the answer. I will check the guidelines.

Comment: Let me know if my answer worked for you

Comment: Web browser is opening but the key word is not searched and specific keyword searched site is not opening.

Comment: sure, my code is missing some code you already have. Will update it to make it clear

Comment: Still the web page is opening but it is not searched the keyword and specific keyword site is not opening. I get the following log once the code is executed . <selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains.ActionChains at 0x1abf6b19af0>

Comment: I really appreciate your help. Still i have the above mentioned problem

Comment: But before my changes the browser was opened and the site was opened and the search field was found and the search text string was inserted there?

Comment: Yes, earlier the search string was inserted but the new site based on the search string was not opened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, Hope this works

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as wait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

browser = webdriver.Firefox()

browser.get("https://www.tickertape.in/stocks/")
browser.maximize_window()
inputElement=browser.find_element_by_id('search-stock-input')
inputElement.click()
inputElement.send_keys('Reliance industries')
inputElement.click()

inputElement = wait(browser, 5).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#search-stock-input")))
inputElement.click()
inputElement.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try sending the text with `actions`, not with `driver`. This will perform it slowly and possibly resolve the problem of suggested results.
Also try sending `Enter` key to the search field instead of clicking there.
Also you should add wait to let the search field element be fully rendered.
As following:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

browser = webdriver.Firefox()

wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 20)
actions = ActionChains(browser)

browser.get("https://www.tickertape.in/stocks/")
browser.maximize_window()
input_element = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#search-stock-input")))
actions.move_to_element(input_element)
actions.click()
actions.send_keys('Reliance industries')
actions.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```

In case the

```
actions.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```

not worked you can try

```
actions.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```